# MKOverlayView usage Sample Code

Tags: ios4, gps, core-location, mkoverlay

I would like to make an app to track running routes (real-time) on a map.
I think I have to use CoreLocation(GPS) and MKOverlayView (to draw routes on map).

But I couldn't find appropriate sample code on the internet.

Is there any good sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this [tutorial](http://sugartin.info/2011/10/12/drawing-route-on-google-map-mkmapview/) for drawing the path in my app. The author explained very clearly. Hope this help.

This is new [link](http://iosrider.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/draw-route-between-two-location/)